# Centos how to set sys path `/usr/lib/python2.7` to `/usr/lib64/python2.7`

Tags: python, centos

In centos7 sys path are showing:

```
[root@centos]# python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

I want to replace with below path:

```
[root@centos]# python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
['', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/centos/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

please guide me how to change.

Comment: `[x.replaced('lib', 'lib64') for x in myList]` ? But I think that's not the answer you're excepting :p

Comment: Presumably, you want to use a different Python installed on your machine where `sys.path` is the list you want.

Comment: I have install python again but still path pointing to `/usr/lib/python2.7`